# JQUERY не видит input-ы

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS:

```
$('.calc-chbox input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
console.log('chk');
```

Изначально(работает):

```
<div class="calc-chbox">
            <div id="calc-services" style="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" 
 id="calc-chbox" name="calc-services[]" value="2"> Услуга1</label><br>
   <label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="calc-chbox" name="calc-services[]" 
 value="7"> Услуга2</label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Потом JS:

```
$('#calc-services').html('<label><input type="checkbox" id="calc-chbox" 
name="calc-services" value="4">Проверка</label><br>');
```

И уже это не работает JS:

```
$('.ab-calc .calc-chbox input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
console.log('chk');
```

Comment: `.change(` заменить на `.on('change'`. ps один минус от меня за "робит"

Comment: Вы удаляете dom элемент, обработчик его при этом тоже удаляется и его нужно инициализировать снова.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev [будьте дружелюбнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) :) это нормальное русское слово (словарь Даля), очень редкое в употреблении. Преимущественно можно услышать в старых селах и деревнях нашей страны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После редактирования DOM.
События на задетые элементы надо навешивать заного:

```
$('#calc-services').html('<label><input type="checkbox" id="calc-chbox" 
name="calc-services" value="4">Проверка</label><br>');
$('.ab-calc .calc-chbox input[type=checkbox]').change(...);
```

Comment: Не подумал об этом, спасибо,